# Decrease or sweep token is not approved uniswapV3?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

I call a transaction to increase liquidity on UniswapV3 with NonfungiblePositionManager contract to a position that i don't own. Here is the txn hash on goerli: 0x8c348e3220a215a543899f9cb36a4ea4d9876b3543877b83872f6d2ecfbc87ae

I want to withdraw my tokens but when calling decrease liquidity or burn or sweep token it fail as not approved. So how to ressolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase liquidity of a position you don't own, as it doesn't check owner there, however *ONLY*  The owner address can remove liquidity